# How to set the cell width in html?

Tags: html

I have a table with 2 rows as shown in below but am unable to fix the cells width as shown in below how can we fix the cell width? When I am trying to fix the cell3 width it automatically fixes cell1 width also

```
Cell1          |   cell2
Cell3    |    cell4
```

Comment: A "table" where the cell boundaries are not supposed to line up almost certainly shouldn't be expressed as a table. This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You seem to be working from a false premise (using a table) and you haven't explained enough about the problem (to the extent that you've got fake data that we can't infer anything from in your example) for us to determine how you should go about it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Specify in each `td` a width, something like `<td width="20%">`, `<td width="30%">`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the col tag to do table styling in one place for all rows but you will need to set the table-layout:fixed style on the table or the tables css class and set the overflow style for the cells

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp

```
<table class="fixed">
<col width="20px" />
<col width="30px" />
<col width="40px" />
<tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

and this be your CSS

```
table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use colspan property of table for this.

```
<table>

 <col width="20px" />
 <col width="30px" />
 <col width="40px" />
 <tr>
<td>text</td>
<td colspan=2>text</td>
<td>text</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td colspan=2>text</td>
<td >text</td>
</tr>

<table>
```

it looks like this

```
 text text    text
 text     text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <caption>Table Name</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
th {
    width: 100px; /* or the width you want */
}
```

Manipulating the `th` will make its corresponding `td`s to adjust accordingly. Just make sure the number of your `th`s corresponds to the number of your `td`s. You can also use `colspan` *(see example in the `tfoot`)* if you want to merge the `th`s or `td`s.